Webscraping data limit
Im trying to scrape prices of all listings on the page: https://www.otodom.pl/pl/wyniki/wynajem/kawalerka/cala-polska?ownerTypeSingleSelect=ALL&viewType=listing but Im getting only 3 out of 36. All listings (and their prices) are in the same element.
Is it possible that website is blocking too many requests or did I screw up somewhere in code?
import requests

headers = {
 "User-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

req = requests.get("https://www.otodom.pl/pl/wyniki/wynajem/kawalerka/cala-polska?ownerTypeSingleSelect=ALL&viewType=listing", headers=headers)
req = req.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(req, 'html.parser')

rent_prices = []
ul = soup.find('ul', class_='css-rqwdxd e127mklk0')
lis = ul.find_all('li')

for li in lis:
    price = li.find_all('span', class_='css-1uwck7i evk7nst0')
    rent_prices.append([price])

And rent_prices outcomes:

[[[<span class="css-1uwck7i evk7nst0" direction="horizontal">2499 zł<style data-emotion="css v14eu1">.css-v14eu1{color:#495260;font-size:14px;font-weight:400;}</style><span class="css-v14eu1 evk7nst1">+ <!-- -->czynsz: 680 zł/miesiąc</span></span>]],
 [[<span class="css-1uwck7i evk7nst0" direction="horizontal">2300 zł</span>]],
 [[<span class="css-1uwck7i evk7nst0" direction="horizontal">5098 zł</span>]]]


That website have 2 sections with listing. One is promoted listing and one is organic listing. You are getting the data only from the promoted section. So you have screwed up somewhere on your code.

Look more closely at the HTML on the target site.  You're fetching all of the target records within a single parent <ul> element here:
ul = soup.find('ul', class_='css-rqwdxd e127mklk0')
lis = ul.find_all('li')

for li in lis:
    price = li.find_all('span', class_='css-1uwck7i evk7nst0')
    rent_prices.append([price])

However, there are two matching <ul> elements.  The first one contains three <li> elements, representing the data you're currently finding.  The second one contains the rest.
Aggregate the data from all of the matching <ul> elements:
uls = soup.find_all('ul', class_='css-rqwdxd e127mklk0')
for ul in uls:
    lis = ul.find_all('li')

    for li in lis:
        price = li.find_all('span', class_='css-1uwck7i evk7nst0')
        rent_prices.append([price])


To get the data I'd use their Ajax pagination API:
import requests

api_url = "https://www.otodom.pl/_next/data/9-efWT4JwTc5zPjzGI6Ol/pl/wyniki/wynajem/kawalerka/cala-polska.json"

params = {
    "ownerTypeSingleSelect": "ALL",
    "viewType": "listing",
    "searchingCriteria": ["wynajem", "kawalerka", "cala-polska"],
    "page": "1",
}

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:126.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/126.0"
}

for params["page"] in range(1, 3):  # <-- increase number of pages here.
    data = requests.get(api_url, params=params, headers=headers).json()

    for ad in data["pageProps"]["data"]["searchAds"]["items"]:
        print(ad["title"])
        # print(ad["totalPrice"])
        # ...

    print("-" * 80)

Prints:

...

Jednoosobowa umeblowana kawalerka ul.Słowackiego
Bezczynszowe !!!
Kawalerka 30m2 ul. Stawiszyńska
Funkcjonalna, nowa kawalerka Bez Prowizji
Studio z balkonem w apartamentowcu z windą z 2020r
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Mieszkanie 1pok. w Czempiniu, pl. Zielony Rynek
Metro, wszystko w cenie, Kawalerka / Studio
Umeblowana kawalerka 38,8m2, Włocławek - Centrum
BEZPOŚREDNIO Przytulna kawalerka Koszutka
Kawalerka centrum z parkingiem
Studio 86 m2, Stare Miasto, Librowszczyzna
Apartament z parkingiem , do zamieszkania od zaraz
Kawalerka z garażem, Gdańsk Jasień, ul. Kartuska
gotowe do wprowadzenia +msc. postojowe
Nowoczesna kawalerka w centrum Gogolina

...

